# Trying to copy a cell formula with a dynamic range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Trying to figure out how copy and paste a formula using Google Script in google sheets.  When I use the getFormula and setFormula it does copy the formula but it keeps the same range, it does not dynamically update the range like it normally does when you use the spreadsheet without a script.  Wondering what I am doing wrong... here is my code

```
     var source = formulaSheet.getRange(row+1,col-1).getFormula();
     var target = formulaSheet.getRange(row+1,col);
     target.setFormula(source);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use R1C1 notation instead of A1 as the first allows to use relative coordinates. For this you could use [getformular1c1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformular1c1) and/or [getformulasr1c1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulasr1c1) and the corresponding "set" versions.